# Delegate doesn't get called from another viewcontroller, tried everything

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, delegates, viewcontroller

I have 2 viewcontrollers, with a segue between them. My main viewcontroller is called `ViewController`. in my second viewcontroller called `PreferencesViewController` I have a button that has to change some values in my main ViewController. But it doesn't...

I have set up a delegate protocol in my `PreferencesViewController.h` like I saw on a few examples on Stack Overflow (yes I did google it ;) ).

I also have imported the `PreferencesViewController.h` file to my main ViewController, aswell I told the viewcontroller to be the delegate: `<PreferencesViewControllerDelegate>`

I also implemented the method in my implementation of the main ViewController. But this method doesn't get called when I press the button. I implemented `[self.delegate methodExample];` in to my IBAction

I've read a lot about setting the delegate. Where do I need to do this? do I need to create and alloc/init a instance of my `PreferenceViewController`? I tried this and then told the instance `instance.delegate = self` but that didn't work also...

Hope someone can help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that you need to set the delegate. The easiest place to do this when using segues is in the source view controller (`ViewController`, in this case) using he `prepareForSegue:sender:` method. The segue object passed to this method has a reference to the destination view controller; you probably want to do something like:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Your preferences segue identifier"]) {
        PreferencesViewController *preferencesViewController = 
segue.destinationViewController;
        preferencesViewController.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

Since you're using segues, the system is doing the alloc/init of the new view controller for you; this method is called by the system to let you do any hooking up of the new view controller before it's displayed.